# Observing bits from a variable in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, binary-data

I would like to read in a number, say a float, and allow the user to see what bit pattern is responsible for their input. How do I allow a variable to be printed or stored as an int or array as simple binary values instead of 0-9 or a-z, etc?

This doesn't do what I want it to. It instead gives an int with digits 0-9, which is obviously not a binary number.

```
int main(){

cout << "Please enter a float number." << endl;
float number;
    cin >> number;

    int bits = *((int*) &number);

    cout << number << endl;

    cout << bits << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C or C++?  Your code is C++, but you've tagged the question with both.

Comment: Actually, my code is in C, but I suppose given the proper includes, etc, would work in C++. I tagged with both because I would accept a solution in either.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest (and C-friendly) way to do what you're trying to is to employ a pointer to `char` and use it to access the individual bytes of the `float` variable:

```
unsigned char *b = (unsigned char *)&number;
```

Then iterate over the bytes:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof number; i++)
{
    printf("%02x", b[i]);
}
```

Note that this approach prints out a hexadecimal value, but that's directly convertible to a binary representation if you really want to do it that way:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof number; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < CHAR_BIT; j++)
    {
        printf("%d", (b[i] >> j) & 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For data of types such as `int`, `char`, you could just print them with "%x" to get their binary representations. But floating point number is different, you usually need an union at here. For example, to get the binary representation of `1.2` as a double, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    union {
        double number;
        unsigned char bytes[sizeof(double)];
    } double_bytes;

    double_bytes.number = 1.2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) {
        printf("%x ", double_bytes.bytes[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

This version also include the binary representation, which sometimes is harder to understand than hexadecimal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *
byte2bin(char buf[10], unsigned char ch)
{
    char *bins[] = {
        "0000", "0001", "0010", "0011",
        "0100", "0101", "0110", "0111",
        "1000", "1001", "1010", "1011",
        "1100", "1101", "1110", "1111",
    };

    sprintf(buf, "%s %s", bins[(ch & 0xf0)>>4], bins[ch & 0xf]);
    return buf;
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    union {
        double number;
        unsigned char bytes[sizeof(double)];
    } double_bytes;

    double_bytes.number = 1.2;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(double); i++) {
        printf("%x ", (unsigned int)double_bytes.bytes[i] & 0xff);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for (size_t i = 0; i< sizeof(double); i++) {
        char buf[10] = { '\0' };
        printf("%s ", byte2bin(buf, double_bytes.bytes[i]));
    }
    printf("\n");

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Compiled with GCC 4.7.2: `gcc -std=c99`

Output:

```
$ ./a.out 
33 33 33 33 33 33 f3 3f 
0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 0011 1111 0011 0011 1111
```

I believe those spaces in the output made it a little bit easier for human eyes and minds.

Comment: `printf("%x",...` gives hexadecimal, but good answer otherwise.

Comment: @AndyG Oh, in binary. It is hard to read, but fortunately quite easy to emit. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
std::string to_binary(const T &t)
{
    const char *bytes = reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&t);

    std::string result;
    result.reserve(sizeof(t) * CHAR_BIT);

    for (int i = sizeof(t) - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        for (int j = CHAR_BIT - 1; j >= 0; --j)
            result += (bytes[i] & (1 << j) ? '1' : '0');
    }

    return result;
}
```

will return a string containing the bits of a variable, starting with the most-significant bit.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using bit fields.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) has pretty good explanation of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the size of the float (or any other type) and then cast the address of the value to unsigned int*. I give a tested example below which prints the float in hex on my system.

Edited to add display of DW and Bits:

```
float myVal = 1.0;

cout << "In raw DW/Bin:" << endl;

for (unsigned int loop=0; loop<sizeof(float)/sizeof (unsigned int);loop++)
{
    unsigned int val = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int*>(&myVal)[loop];

    cout << hex << val << " - " << bitset<32>(val) << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
In raw DW/Bin:
3f800000 - 00111111100000000000000000000000
```